# Замена элементов массива местами

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.x

Подскажите, почему работает только когда минимальный и максимальный элемент идут по возрастающему порядку? Т.е только один раз.

```
a = input().split()
a = [int(i) for i in a]
a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
print(a)
a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, вычисление максимального и минимального элемента и их индексов происходит прямо во время обмена элементов.

Нужно до обмена высчитать индексы.

---

Давайте добавим логирование обращения к оператору квадратных скобок и посмотрим что выведется для текущего алгоритма и правильного:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(f'__getitem__[{item}]')
        return super().__getitem__(item)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'__setitem__[{key}] = {value!r}')
        return super().__setitem__(key, value)

a = '123456789'
a = [int(i) for i in a]
a = MyList(a)
```

Алгоритм из вопроса:

```
a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
print(a)
# __getitem__[8]
# __getitem__[0]
# __setitem__[0] = 9
# __setitem__[0] = 1
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Правильный алгоритм:

```
i_min = a.index(min(a))
i_max = a.index(max(a))
a[i_min], a[i_max] = a[i_max], a[i_min]
print(a)
# __getitem__[8]
# __getitem__[0]
# __setitem__[0] = 9
# __setitem__[8] = 1
# [9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

---

**PS.**

`__getitem__` -- это выражения в правой части, `__setitem__` -- в левой, т.е. когда выполняется присваивание

Answer (score 2):

Потому что при множественном присваивании не стоит в индексах изменяемого объекта писать выражения, которые зависят от самого этого объекта.

У вас индекс второго элемента (который прямо перед равно) вычисляется уже после того, как первый элемент был изменён, поэтому и происходит не совсем то, что ожидалось.

Если вы вычислите индексы до того, как начнёте делать присваивания, то всё будет работать:

```
a = [5, 1, 3]

imin = a.index(min(a))
imax = a.index(max(a))

a[imin], a[imax] = a[imax], a[imin]
print(a)

imin = a.index(min(a))
imax = a.index(max(a))

a[imin], a[imax] = a[imax], a[imin]
print(a)
```